Getting warning message 'Misuse of Sign in with Google API' in 'Android Lint: Correctness'
I am seeing a warning message in Android Studio when I inspect my project.
in 'Android Lint: Correctness', the warning is:

Misuse of Sign in with Google API,
Use of :googleid classes without use of GoogleIdTokenCredential.


Detailed description of warnings:

Misuse of Sign in with Google APIWhen using :googleid classes like GetGoogleIdOption and GetSignInWithGoogleOption, you typically must handle the response using GoogleIdTokenCredential.TYPE_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_CREDENTIAL or GoogleIdTokenCredential. TYPE_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_SIWG_CREDENTIAL.This check reports all uses of these :googleid classes if there are no references to GoogleIdTokenCredential.Issue id: CredentialManagerSignInWithGooglehttps://developer.android.com/identity/sign-in/credential-manager-siwg#create-sign

I checked the link given above and I followed the documentation in that link.
I have searched a lot on google search engine and stack overflow about this.  I also asked AI for advice on this, tried restarting Android Studio.
Every time I do code inspection I get the same warning message.
My code:
In build.gradle
dependencies {
     // dependencies for credential
    implementation("androidx.credentials:credentials-play-services-auth:1.2.2")
    implementation("com.google.android.libraries.identity.googleid:1.1.1")
}

In Fragment
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val googleIdOption by lazy {
            GetGoogleIdOption.Builder().setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
                .setServerClientId(serverClientId)
                .setAutoSelectEnabled(true).setNonce(generateNonce()).build()
        }

        val request: androidx.credentials.GetCredentialRequest =
            androidx.credentials.GetCredentialRequest.Builder().addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
                .build()

        val mContext = requireContext()
        val credentialManager by lazy { androidx.credentials.CredentialManager.create(mContext) }

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            try {
                val result = credentialManager.getCredential(
                    request = request,
                    context = mContext,
                )
                handleSignIn(result)
            } catch (e: androidx.credentials.exceptions.GetCredentialException) {
                showMessage("Failed to get credential: $e")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun handleSignIn(result: androidx.credentials.GetCredentialResponse) {
        when (val credential = result.credential) {
            is CustomCredential -> {
                if (credential.type == GoogleIdTokenCredential.TYPE_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_CREDENTIAL) {
                    try {
                        val googleIdTokenCredential =
                            GoogleIdTokenCredential.createFrom(credential.data)

                        val id = googleIdTokenCredential.id
                        val displayName = googleIdTokenCredential.displayName

                        if (displayName == null) {
                            showMessage("Login Failed\nid: $id")
                            return
                        }

                    } catch (e: GoogleIdTokenParsingException) {
                        showMessage("Received an invalid google id token response, $e")
                    }
                }
            }

            else -> {
                showMessage("Unexpected type of credential")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun generateNonce(): String {
        val nonceBytes = ByteArray(16)
        SecureRandom().nextBytes(nonceBytes)
        return Base64.encodeToString(
            nonceBytes, Base64.NO_PADDING or Base64.NO_WRAP or Base64.URL_SAFE
        )
    }

    private fun showMessage(message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }


Although the same code is not showing me the warning. But I updated the library version.
dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.credentials:credentials-play-services-auth:1.3.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.libraries.identity.googleid:googleid:1.1.1")
}



If want to suppress the warnings, you can use the @SuppressLint annotation
.


Note: This is an Android annotation that helps you ignore certain lint warnings. When you know that a particular piece of code is
causing a warning but is not a problem for your project, you can use
this annotation.

@SuppressLint("deprecation")
fun main() {
    oldApiCall()
}

According to your warning, if you want to ignore it, use the @SuppressLint annotation and provide the issue IDs, such as deprecation, UnusedResources, NewApi,ResourceType etc.

I get this warning only when I inspect the code.

This maybe bug of android studio.
